# In ansible, why am I getting these error when running the script? what is the simple ansible script that i could use to test?

Tags: ansible

I am new to ansible. I just need some examples of start and stop script of anisble to understand. I am also learning to patch using vs code,redhat enterprise.
This error shows up after running the script.
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note
that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'. I am using ubuntu to run the script.

Comment: What do you mean by a "start and stop script"? Have you spent some time reading through [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/)?

Comment: I think this is a valid question - just badly worded. 
The essence is 'why am I getting this [WARNING]?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is just a warning.

I get rid of it if I'm testing locally by explicitly specifying a target. E.g. in `/etc/ansible/hosts` I add:

```
[local_targets]
localhost   ansible_connection=local
```

Another solution is to create an inventory file specifying `localhost`.

Answer (score -1):

Put this

```
#!/usr/local/env ansible-playbook
- name: Run a command on your server
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  become: false
  tasks:
  - name: Print hello world
    debug:
      msg: "Hello world!"
```

in a file and run it

```sh
$ ansible-playbook my-playbook.yml
```

Comment: This does not address the misconception that the OP has about Ansible.

Comment: This answers the stated question: "What is a simple ansible script I could use to test". The existing ansible documentation already adequately describes how to use ansible.